# Subtract wo db fields in crystal reports formula editor

Tags: .net, winforms, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have two business objects of same type `List<DenominationDataEntity>` added to crystal reports.
1. ReceivedDenomination 
2. PaidDenomination.

I have to show the values of both list and then i have to subtract values of both list's fields.
for eg. Both `ReceivedDenomination` and `PaidDenomination` has field `Thousand` now i have to subtract the value of `ReceivedDenomination.Thousand` and  `PaidDenomination.Thousand`. I have created Formula Field with the following code.

```
Global numberVar TotalThousand :=0;

(if IsNull({ReceivedDenomination.Thousand}) then
     TotalThousand
else
     TotalThousand := ToNumber({ReceivedDenomination.Thousand})
);

(if IsNull({PaidDenomination.Thousand}) then
    TotalThousand
else
     TotalThousand := TotalThousand + ToNumber({PaidDenomination.Thousand});
);
TotalThousand
```

The problem i am having is the `TotalThousand` field returns wrong answer. i.e. if

`ReceivedDenomination.Thousand` is 85 and the `PaidDenomination.Thousand` is 2 then i am getting 2 instead of 83.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried doing it like this?

```
Global numberVar TotalThousand :=0;
Global numberVar RcvdThou := 0;
Global numberVar PdThou := 0;

(if IsNull({ReceivedDenomination.Thousand}) then
     TotalThousand
else
     RcvdThou := ToNumber({ReceivedDenomination.Thousand})
);

(if IsNull({PaidDenomination.Thousand}) then
    TotalThousand
else
     PdThou := ToNumber({PaidDenomination.Thousand});
);
TotalThousand := RcvdThou + PdThou;
TotalThousand;
```

If this is still giving you an issue, try separating the formula into multiple formulas and seeing what each field is giving you.  So you would have a TotalThousand, RcvdThou, PdThou, and a Total formala.  The TotalThousand would instantiate the global, while the RcvdThou and PdThou would show the 2 numbers, and the Total would provide the math.